# Замена ключевых слов в зарендеренной View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, view, razor

Добрый день, появилась необходимость заменять ключевые слова после отрисовки вьюхи, но перед отправкой ее на клиента. Есть ли возможность сделать это в ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать свой `ActionFilterAttribute`, обработать в нем `OnResultExecuted` и там навесить свой фильтр на response.

```
public abstract class OutputProcessorActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected abstract string Process(string data);

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Filter = new OutputProcessorStream(response.Filter, Process);
    }
}

internal class OutputProcessorStream : Stream
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _data = new StringBuilder();

    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly Func<string, string> _processor;

    public OutputProcessorStream(Stream stream, Func<string, string> processor)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _processor = processor;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _data.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count));
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_stream, _outputEncoding))
        {
            writer.Write(_processor(_data.ToString()));
            writer.Flush();
        }
        _data.Clear();
    }

    ...
}
```

Потом объявить конкретную реализацию фильтра, например:

```
public class ToUpperFilterAttribute : OutputProcessorActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected override string Process(string data)
    {
        return data.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

и навесить его на действие:

```
[ToUpperFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Код взят с [Rico Suter's site](http://blog.rsuter.com/post-process-the-html-output-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc/), там же есть ссылка [на тулкит](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MyToolkit.AspNet.Mvc/Filters/OutputProcessorActionFilterAttribute.cs) и на [github c  полным примером](https://github.com/rsuter/SampleOutputProcessorActionFilter).